# Correct way to denote set of matrices with one $1$ and one $-1$ on the diagonal, zeros elsewhere.

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I am trying to describe the set of roots of a particular Lie algebra representation, and I was looking for suggestions to "clean up" my notation a bit. The roots are $n\times n$ matrices having a $1$ and a $-1$ in the diagonal, and right now I've got something like this:

$$\mathcal{R}=\{(a_{ii})-(a_{jj}):(a_{kk})= \begin{pmatrix}0\\&\ddots\\&&1\\&&&\ddots\\&&&&0\end{pmatrix}\text{, having }1\text{ in the }kk\text{ position.}\}$$

Is there a better way to notate this?

Comment: You can probably do whatever you want.  Something like "let $A_k$ denote the $n \times n$ matrix with a $1$ in the $(k,k)$ entry and zeros elsewhere."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly common notation is to use *matrix units*: that is, $E_{kj}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $k,j$ entry, and zeroes elsewhere. Then you would have 
$$
\mathcal R=\{E_{kk}-E_{jj}:\ k\ne j\}.
$$

Comment: $E_{ii}-E_{ii}=0$.

Comment: Of course. I was thinking of using ones and minus ones. My bad.

Comment: I left the $k\ne j$ in the assumption that you don't want the zero matrix.

Comment: Right, the roots are the *non-zero* weights of the representation. Thanks.